# What is the http_response_code equivalent for an nginx server?

Tags: apache, nginx, httpresponse

I have built a RESTful API in which I set the http_response_code() in some cases. I was using the XAMPP APACHE web server while developing the API on localhost.

The problem is that, now that I have deployed the API on our EC2 containerized DEV instance, which runs an nginx web server, all of my http_response_code() calls are not working and the API is always returning a "200 OK" status code, which is not wanted in cases like an error should be thrown when for example a user already exists in the system and a registration with the same email is forbidden.

Therefore, is there an equivalent of http_response_code() for nginx web servers?

Comment: Are you referring to the `http_response_code()` PHP function?

Comment: Yes. What i'm starting to realize is that it doesn't have to do with the PHP function but with the server configuration. The NGINX server doesn't let the PHP function to change the status code of the response for some reason.